# Facing issue while creating admin user with rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ubuntu 18.4, ruby 2.7.3 and railes 4.2.11.1, gem version 3.1.6.
While running rake admin:create i am getting following error message.

```
$ rake admin:create
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined method `extend_object' for class `Singleton'
Did you mean?  extended
/home/ubuntu/cenit/config/application.rb:4:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/cenit/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/cenit/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: "Creating an admin user" with what? Where does the `admin:create` task come from? Are you talking about Discourse?

Comment: Actually i am trying to install the IPaaS platform in ubuntu as per the instruction given in https://cenit-io.github.io/docs/#/